# MeteorJS - skip package update during meteor build

Tags: node.js, npm, meteor, auto-update, atmosphere

I have a MeteorJS project with several internal packages (in the packages/ dir). During meteorbundle in the build stage of my project, meteor tries to update npm dependencies of one specific package, which causes UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE error and stops the bundle.

So I have two problems:

1. How to prevent update of the npm dependencies of that package?
2. If it cannot be prevented, how to turn off certificate verification in that process?

Things that I've tried and did not help:

- NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
- METEOR_OFFLINE_CATALOG=1
- npm config set strict-ssl=false
- meteor npm config set strict-ssl=false

It should be noted that meteor npm install works fine, one meteor build fails.

Comment: How do you deploy? Galaxy, MUP, manually?

Comment: I deploy the app manually, by running a container that executes "node main.js" in the bundle directory